# Как запустить отладку asp.net core приложения только с kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel

Хочу запустить asp.net core приложение, из visual studio, только с помощью kestrel без использования IIS/IISExpres так как это происходит при выполнении команды dotnet run.
Последовательность действий:
Создаю приложение asp.net core WebApi, в свойствах проекта выбираю профиль моего приложения и нажимаю f5. Неизменно запускается IIS, я делаю такое заключение поскольку приложение запускается не на http://localhost:5000 - url указанный для моего профиля, и не открывается консоль.

Мой метод CreateWebHostBuilder:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel();
}
}
```

Мой launchSettings.json:

```
{
      "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6000",
          "sslPort": 0
        }
      },
      "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
      "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "launchUrl": "api/values",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
        },
    "MyProfile": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          },
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то на кнопке IIS Express есть вариант запуска консольным приложением. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS6mu.jpg

Comment: Эм. все же хотелось бы чтобы там не было IIS, а только kestrel. Тут https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.7.php пишут, что нужно просто выбрать профиль своего приложения, но у меня это почему-то не работает.

Comment: Ну так вырежьте все ненужные профили, делов-то? Оформил ответом, чтобы с картинками было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыл студию, создал пустой API проект. В нём две кнопки: одна для запуска IIS Express на рандомном порту, другая - для запуска приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываю файл launchSettings.json убираю узлы iisSettings и IIS Express:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как только нажимаю сохранить - на кнопке остаётся только один профиль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бинго?

Comment: если почистить кэш и пересобрать проект,  launchSettings.json будет создан заново, и проект по дефолту будет запускаться через iis.